# How to remove has focus line in ion input?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I try integrate a button to show the input password but ion-item have a line bottom. I need hide that line y tryed hide with scss but its'n work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Item</title>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@4.7.4/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@4.7.4/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@4.7.4/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>
  <style>
    :root {
      --ion-safe-area-top: 20px;
      --ion-safe-area-bottom: 22px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ion-app>

    <ion-content fullscreen class="ion-padding">
        <ion-item class="form-login">
          <!-- Input password -->
          <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="text-primary"></ion-input>
          <!-- Button password -->
          <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" (click)="showPassword()">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="eye"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-remove-has-focus-line-in-ion-input/150029/5

```
ion-item {
  --highlight-color-focused: none;
}
```